# Sum using from clause (linq)

Tags: c#, linq, clause

I've got a following command:

```
var sum = myList.Sum(p => p.Field);
```

Is it possible to write the same command using from clause? eg.

```
var sum = from myList ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no expression for sum in this notation. Here is as close as you can get:

```
var sum = (from p in myList select p.Field).Sum();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yep. See below.

```
var sum = (from p in myList
           select p.Field).Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var sum = (from p in myList
           select p.Field).Sum();
```

- [`Enumerable.Sum` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx)